# jquery classifying flip switches without using div

Tags: jquery, html

I want two jquery flip switches to be in one line and one of them not be visible when the screen is too narrow.

For them to be treated differently, they need to be assigned different classes, but that somehow does not work. when the class or id is assigned to  a p or div, the condition works, but then those elements appear not in one line.

how to assign to them some classes while keeping them in one line?

Comment: Can you show us some code? Perhaps [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Sure: 
http://jsbin.com/inunev/4/edit.
BOth flips are apparently controlled by the div setting; bigga class applied to one of them does not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

what works best is using a table with one row, two columns.

Comment: Can you provide some code for this? It's great that you're answering your question to help others, but both your question and answer lack code and context that would help anyone find it.

Answer (score 0):

and here is the same thing done by means of css, which is said to be more suited for object positioning than js. indeed, to this version dreamweaver responds instantly whenever you change it live mode's resolution.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"> 
</script><script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"> </script>
<style>
@media screen and (min-width:1px) and (max-width:319px) {
.bigga {
    display: none;
}
}
div.ui-slider-switch {
    width: 7em
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width="200" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center" class="bigga">
        <select data-role="slider" >
          <option value="off">boy</option>
          <option value="on"> girl</option>
        </select>
      </div></td>
    <td><div  align="center">
        <form >
          <select data-role="slider" >
            <option value="off" accesskey=""    >man</option>
            <option value="on"  > woman</option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```